# Alamofire HTTP post request in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, alamofire

I'm trying to make an HTTP request to a link; the response is in JSON.

I can't get the response correctly. I'm new with Swift and I don't know what the problem is…

The URL I'm trying to reach is **http://url/test.r&pcTest=pTest**

I already done this but in Objective C:

```
NSString *serviceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url/test.r&pcTest=pTest"];

 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[serviceURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
if (!data) {
    NSLog(@"null");
}

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;

if (![response isEqualToString:@"UNAUTHORIZED"]) {
    response = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&#x26;"];
    data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
} else {
    //return nil;
    NSLog(@"dsfg");
}
```

And I got a correct answer. In Swift my code is:

```
let parameters = ["pcTest": "pTest"]
let urlPath :String = "http://url/test.r"
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlPath, parameters: parameters)
         .response { request, response, data, error in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)
            println(data)
    }
```

The response is

> **{ URL: http://url/test.r }**
>
> **Optional( { URL: http://url/test.r} { status code: 200, headers {
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Type" = "text/javascript; charset=iso-8859-1";
>       Date = "Fri, 11 Sep 2015 22:34:12 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=400";
>       Server = "Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8c";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity; } })**
>
> **nil**
>
> **Optional(<7b227474 41706172 7461646f 223a5b7b 22416e6f 223a2232 30313422 2c224376 655f4170 6172745f 4576616c 7561223a 22303122
>   2c224465 73637269 7063696f 6e223a22 43616c69 64616420 656e2065
>   6c204465 73656d70 65f16f20 446f6365 6e746522 7d2c7b22 416e6f22
>   3a223230 3134222c 22437665 5f417061 72745f45 76616c75 61223a22
>   3032222c 22446573 63726970 63696f6e 223a2244 65646963 616369f3
>   6e206120 6c617320 41637469 76696461 64657320 64652044 6f63656e
>   63696122 7d2c7b22 416e6f22 3a223230 3134222c 22437665 5f417061
>   72745f45 76616c75 61223a22 3033222c 22446573 63726970 63696f6e
>   223a2250 65726d61 6e656e63 69612065 6e206c61 73204163 74697669
>   64616465 73206465 20446f63 656e6369 61227d5d 2c227474 53656363
>   696f6e22 3a5b7b22 416e6f22 3a223230 3134222c 22437665 5f417061
>   72745f45 76616c75 61223a22 3031222c 22437665 5f536563 635f4576
>   616c7561 223a2230 31222c22**

The response should be:

> **{"Bank":[{"Year":"2014","Clv":"01","Desc":"1345"},{"Year":"2014","Clv ... etc, etc**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want JSON parsing, you need to call `responseJSON`, not `response`:

```
let parameters = ["pcTest": "pTest"]
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://url/test.r", parameters: parameters)
         .responseJSON { _, _, result in
             print(result)
             debugPrint(result)
         }
```

Comment: I tried to implement your answer but the output is:
nil nil

Comment: Then either (1) the server is not responding to your request with JSON, (2) the content-type is not valid, or (3) the HTTP status code does not indicate succcess

Comment: Yeah, I got this error:
(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 67.) UserInfo=0x7fede1e436b0 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 67.})

Comment: Sounds like your server isn't using UTF encoding, which is required by the JSON spec

Comment: In your Objective-C code, you're using ASCII encoding, which is not part of the JSON spec. You will have to manually convert the data in Swift just like you did in Obj-C.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept your answer for your help! Btw, do you know how I could convert the data in Swift?